# Pandas, merging two rows with different index names

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame, `df`, that looks like this:

```
              Done  Todo  Total                     
Painting       55    54    109
Fitting        17    26     43
Plumbing       10    26     36
Electricity     7    29     36
Piping         29     5     34
Roofing        12    20     32
```

I need to merge indexes 'Plumbing' and 'Piping' so that I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
              Done  Todo  Total                     
Painting       55    54    109
Fitting        17    26     43
Plumbing       39    46     68
Electricity     7    29     36
Piping         29     5     34
```

How can I achieve this is pandas?

I have tried the following

```
df.loc['Plumbing'] = df.loc['Plumbing'] + df.loc['Piping']
```

but this keeps the 'Piping' row in the data frame. Is there a way of doing it automatically so that the 'Piping row is automatically removed?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438906/combining-rows-in-pandas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684346/pandas-group-by-operations-on-a-data-frame) questions did not provide what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easier is drop.

But you can [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) values in index (first call [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html), because `replace` is not implemented in `index`) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by index with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df.index = df.index.to_series().replace({'Piping':'Plumbing'}) 
print df
             Done  Todo  Total
Painting       55    54    109
Fitting        17    26     43
Plumbing       10    26     36
Electricity     7    29     36
Plumbing       29     5     34
Roofing        12    20     32

print df.groupby(df.index, sort=False).sum()
             Done  Todo  Total
Painting       55    54    109
Fitting        17    26     43
Plumbing       39    31     70
Electricity     7    29     36
Roofing        12    20     32
```

Answer (score 3):

Its not automaticaly but:

```
df.loc['Plumbing'] = df.loc['Plumbing'] + df.loc['Piping']
df.drop('Piping',axis=0,inplace=True)
```