# Indexing a data frame after performing an operation on a grouped object and creating a variable accordingly

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 Id  Category  Score
 1     M        0.2
 2     C        0.4
 2     M        0.3
 1     C        0.1
 2     M        0.3
 1     M        0.2
 1     C        0.1
 1     C        0.1
 2     C        0.4
```

I want to group by `Id` and `Category`, then find the max Score, and create a new variable called `Category_Label` whose rows are equal to the `Category` at max score index.

The output should look like this

```
 Id  Category  Score    Category_Label
 1     M        0.2          M
 2     C        0.4          C
 2     M        0.3          C
 1     C        0.1          M
 2     F        0.03         C
 1     M        0.2          M
 1     C        0.1          M  
 1     E        0.01         M
 2     C        0.4          C
```

In other words, the new variable 'Category_Label`should be equal to the row of`Category` that corresponds to the max score of all the 1s

I tried this:

```
 df[df['Category_Label']] == df.loc[df.groupby(['Id','Category'])['Score'].transform(lambda a: a.max())],'Category'  ]
```

But I am far away!! I looked into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684346/pandas-group-by-operations-on-a-data-frame) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200693/python-pandas-how-to-assign-groupby-operation-results-back-to-columns-in-parent), but they are not helpful enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use `idxmax` to find where the `max` positions are.
- Use `transform` to broadcast across all indices.
- Use results in `loc` to grab `Category` values
- Assign to a new column

---

```
df.assign(
    Category_Label=df.loc[
        df.groupby('Id').Score.transform('idxmax'),
        'Category'
    ].values
)

   Id Category  Score Category_Label
0   1        M    0.2              M
1   2        C    0.4              C
2   2        M    0.3              C
3   1        C    0.1              M
4   2        M    0.3              C
5   1        M    0.2              M
6   1        C    0.1              M
7   1        C    0.1              M
8   2        C    0.4              C
```

Comment: @JohnGalt reading the question, OP said by `['Id', 'Category']`.  However, that makes no sense.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I like your solution, this is much cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `apply` and get `Score` `idxmax`, use it for `Category` value. Then use, that for `map` of `Id`

```
In [1591]: df.Id.map(df.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.Score.idxmax(), 'Category']))
Out[1591]:
0    M
1    C
2    C
3    M
4    C
5    M
6    M
7    M
8    C
Name: Id, dtype: object
```

Details

```
In [1592]: df.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.Score.idxmax(), 'Category'])
Out[1592]:
Id
1    M
2    C
dtype: object

In [1593]: df['Category_Label'] = df.Id.map(
                              df.groupby('Id')
                                .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.Score.idxmax(), 'Category']))

In [1594]: df
Out[1594]:
   Id Category  Score Category_Label
0   1        M    0.2              M
1   2        C    0.4              C
2   2        M    0.3              C
3   1        C    0.1              M
4   2        M    0.3              C
5   1        M    0.2              M
6   1        C    0.1              M
7   1        C    0.1              M
8   2        C    0.4              C
```

Comment: "1594"... Time to restart the REPL :p

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try without `groupby`

```
df.merge(df.sort_values(['Id','Score']).\
   drop_duplicates(['Id'],keep ='last')[['Id','Category']],on='Id',how='left').\
   rename(columns={'Category_x':'Category','Category_y':'Category_Label'})



Out[176]: 
   Id Category  Score Category_Label
0   1        M   0.20          M
1   2        C   0.40          C
2   2        M   0.30          C
3   1        C   0.10          M
4   2        F   0.03          C
5   1        M   0.20          M
6   1        C   0.10          M
7   1        E   0.01          M
8   2        C   0.40          C
```