# Combining rows using a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe and the goal is combine like values in a row. However these like values have different prices associated with them. So my question is how do I combine all like rows in column PO Material as well as have all the values in Amount_USD be add up to formulate one value.

```
  PO Material.      Material Desc.Amount_USD PO_Pur_Org Count          Total
0   6001488.0   SCRAP: Light (L/S)  485.33300   SA02    4624    2.244180e+06
1   6001488.0   SCRAP: Light (L/S)  728.00000   SA02    1888    1.374464e+06
2   6001488.0   SCRAP: Light (L/S)  242.66700   SA02    1778    4.314619e+05
3   6001488.0   SCRAP: Light (L/S)  606.66700   SA02    1044    6.333603e+05
```

Comment: Can you put the expected results to showcase what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group by operations on a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684346/pandas-group-by-operations-on-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you will want to use `groupby` to find the like values in PO Material, then sum the Amount_USD.

Try this:

```
df.groupby('PO Material')['Amount_USD'].sum()
```

Comment: wow its that simple I didnt think of it that way I thought I had to iterate through the rows with a specific function. thanks

Comment: I learned it the same way you did, right here on StackOverflow. Now, if you would be so kind as to mark that answer as accepted, if it worked for you :)